# Logging not working in laravel queue job

Tags: logging, laravel-5, queue, jobs

I have the below settings in my supervisor/conf.d/myconf.conf file :

```
[program:my-worker]    
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d    
command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work sqs --queue=my_queue_name --tries=3 --daemon    
autostart=true    
autorestart=true    
user=root    
numprocs=1    
redirect_stderr=true    
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/mylogfile.log
```

I have give all permissions to storage/logs/mylogfile.log file.
Not able to figure out why is it still not logging,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I guess you are using Daily logs.

When we have single log file then we have one log file : "**laravel.log**" which we give full permission [777],
so we are able to log and everything works as expected.

But when we have daily file selected then each day the laravel app will create a new file whenever it needs to log something.
Now this file's owner is the web server (**daemon/www-root**) because laravel is run by the user **daemon/www-root**.

When the queue is getting processed the user in action is "**cli**", and it does not have permission to write to this file. so it throws an exception and the processing stops.

What I would suggest to do if you are using daily logs is change monolog settings so that for different users different log files will be created.

Add this code to `bootstrap/app.php`

```
/**
 * Configure Monolog.
 */
$app->configureMonologUsing( function( Monolog\Logger $monolog) {
    $processUser = posix_getpwuid( posix_geteuid() );
    $processName= $processUser[ 'name' ];

    $filename = storage_path( 'logs/laravel-' . php_sapi_name() . '-' . $processName . '.log' );
    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler( $filename );
    $monolog->pushHandler( $handler );
});
```

Just before retrurning the app.

Now you will have log files for cli too, and everything related to queue will be logged in that file.

This also keeps log files clean. HTTP app logs will be in different file and the Queue processing logs will be in different file.

Also please don't forget to run following commands.

> To make sure new config is loaded correctly

```
php artisan config:clear
```

> As you are using supervisor daemon queue worker, so you will need to broadcast the queue restart signal.

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I couldn't make this work with Laravel 5.7. Is there another way to achieve it in the updated version? `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configureMonologUsing()`

Comment: Giving 777 permission on non-public files is strongly discouraged. At least use 755.

Comment: With third digit as 7, you're letting anyone mess with your logging file, even right through the web browser. Stop advising 777

Answer (score 5):

Based on @PrabhatRai answer, here is another configuration example that looks more like Laravel's default behavior.

Add this code to `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function (Monolog\Logger $monolog) {
    $filename = storage_path('logs/' . php_sapi_name() . '-' . posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'] . '.log');
    $monolog->pushHandler($handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($filename, 30));
    $handler->setFilenameFormat('laravel-{date}-{filename}', 'Y-m-d');
    $handler->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));
});
```

- It will store files like this: `laravel-2017-03-27-cli-raph.log` and `laravel-2017-03-27-fpm-cgi-raph.log` which is more readable.
- New lines are preserved (as of default Laravel behavior)
- It works with Laravel Log Viewer

Comment: I couldn't make this work with Laravel 5.7. Is there another way to achieve it in the updated version? `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configureMonologUsing()`

Comment: @makamuevans There you go - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55206727/4705339 - Also make sure you make supervisor use `www-data` user

Answer (score 1):

For solving this problem I did the following :

1. Set the group id of the storage directory and all its sub-directories. Every file created in this directory will have www-data as group.

   ```
   sudo chgrp -r www-data storage
   sudo chmod +R g+s storage
   ```
2. Add the `<user>` running the script to the group www-data

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G www-data user
   ```