# Using configureMonologUsing after Laravel 5.7 upgrade - Supervisor Logging Permission

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5.7, supervisord

I am trying to upgrade my Laravel 5.5 project to 5.7. I use supervisor and before I was using `configureMonologUsing()` to generate the logs but apparently with 5.6 upgrade, it got depreciated. My full code in L5.5 was: in bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing( function( Monolog\Logger $monolog) {
    $processUser = posix_getpwuid( posix_geteuid() );
    $processName= $processUser[ 'name' ];

    $filename = storage_path( 'logs/laravel-' . php_sapi_name() . '-' . $processName . '.log' );
    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler( $filename );
    $monolog->pushHandler( $handler );
});
```

And it was generating various loggers like (which was convenient):

> - laravel-cli-root-{date},
> - laravel-cli-ubuntu-{date},
> - laravel-cli-www-data-{date},
> - laravel-fpm-fcgi-www-data-{date}, etc...

However, it says in the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade) so I can't use `configureMonologUsing` any more:

> The `configureMonologUsing` Method
>
> If you were using the configureMonologUsing method to customize the Monolog instance for your application, you should now create a custom Log channel. For more information on how to create custom channels, check out the [full logging documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#creating-custom-channels).

I couldn't figure out how to achieve the same with logging channels. How can I utilise Monolog Channel to be able to write laravel/storage/logs folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379249/4705339 - This solved my issue!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Taken from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379249/4705339](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379249/4705339_)*

Laravel version 5.6.10 and later has support for a `permission` element in the configuration (`config/logging.php`) for the `single` and the `daily` driver:

```
    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 7,
        'permission' => 0664,    // this line lets the file owner to be www-data:www-data
    ],
```

No need to juggle with Monolog in the bootstrap script.

Specifically, support was added in https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/4d31633dca9594c9121afbbaa0190210de28fed8.